# al insertar formulario con ajax no refresca fromulario

Tags: php, ajax

He creado una insercion con ajax y lo hace perfectamente en la base de datos pero el formulario no refresca o no vuelve a su origen...queda insertado el registro pero ingresa varios copias de registro al insertar el boton o al hacer enter, que puede ser??

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#insertar').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
   var datos=$('#formulario1').serialize();
   $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"insertar.php",
                data:datos,
                async: true,
    success: function(data){
                    $('#respuesta').html(data);
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#respuesta').html(data);
                },
                complete: function(){
                       setTimeout(function() {
                            $('#respuesta').fadeOut();
                       }, 2000);    
                    }
   });
            return; 
  });
 });
        

</script>
```

```html
<form id="formulario1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nombrelibro">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombrelibro" name="nombrelibro" aria-describedby="nombrelibro" placeholder="Inserte nombre Libro">
    <small id="nombrelibro" class="form-text text-muted">Libro sin autor .</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="autor">Autor libro</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="autor" name="autor" placeholder="Indique Autor Libro">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
 <label for="codigo">Codigo</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-3" id="codigo" name="codigo">
    
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="insertar">Insertar</button>
</form>
      <div id="respuesta"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que al tener el formulario con un botón de tipo submit, este te ejecuta una acción y después el ajax otra.

La solución sería quitar una de las dos opciones. Si lo quieres hacer con ajax, tienes que cambiar el type del button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="insertar">Insertar</button>
```

Y en caso de quere hacerlos con el formulario, tienes que añadirle el action y el método al formulario.

```
<form id="formulario1" action="insertar.php" method="POST">
```

En este último caso el button sería del tipo submit.

Comment: Gracias Iñigo Irigoyen Erquicia por tu tiempo y respuesta, pero aun me sigue saliendo lo mismo con el ajuste indica, anexo script php, puede que ahi este el problema..

Comment: <!-- language: lang-php -->
 include("coneccion/conexion.php");

 $nombrelibro =$_POST['nombrelibro'];
 $autor = $_POST['autor'];
 $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];

 $sql="INSERT INTO libros (nombre, autor, codigo)
   VALUES ('$nombrelibro', '$autor', '$codigo')";

if ($conex->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Nuevo libro insertado";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conex->error;
}
$conex->close();

Comment: @actio sería mejor que modificarás tu propia pregunta agregando tu script.php y no aquí en las respuestas.

Comment: eso trato de hacer pero no he podido.... no logro colocar el codigo